# Testing that button starts an Activity with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, robolectric

Hi I have the following code:

```
@RunWith(Test9Runner.class)
public class MainActivityTest 
{
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Button pressMeButton;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        activity = new MainActivity();
        activity.onCreate(null);
        pressMeButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldUpdateResultsWhenButtonIsClicked() throws Exception 
    {
        pressMeButton.performClick();
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(activity);
        Intent intent = shadowActivity.getResultIntent();
        System.out.print(intent.toString());
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to test that pressing pressMeButton started a new Activity. Actually it does, but how to write the correct Robolectric unit test for this fact?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use Robolectric's `StartedMatcher`

```
@RunWith(Test9Runner.class) 
public class MainActivityTest  {
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Button pressMeButton;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        activity = new MainActivity();
        activity.onCreate(null);
        pressMeButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStartNextActivityWhenButtonIsClicked() 
    {
        pressMeButton.performClick();
        assertThat(activity, new StartedMatcher(NextActivity.class));
    }  
}
```

Comment: assertThat causes error: The method assertThat(T, Matcher<T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, Intent)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I corrected the answer. Needs to take an Intent, not an activity. We internally use a helper method that reads "assertThat(activity, started(NextActivity.class));" - much more readable.

Comment: Thought this worked initially and upvoted but it doesn't. Where does this test intercept the Intent raised in performClick? All this test does is construct two Intents and checks if they are equal - which they will never be. Could you clarify this code?

Comment: @JDT you are right, I corrected the last line of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Dongshengcn, Test9Runner is a custom JUnit test runner from the original question, presumably one that extends Robolectric's RobolectricTestRunner.

Comment: StartedMatcher was removed when robolectric moved to 2.0.  Not sure what, if anything, replaced it.

Answer (score 30):

In Robolectric 2.1.1 you can verify if `Intent` starting new `Activity` was emitted in following way.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
  private ShadowActivity shadowActivity;
  private MyActivity activity;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    activity = new MyActivity();
    shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity);        
  }

  @Test
  public shouldStartNewActivityWhenSomething() {
    //Perform activity startup
    //Do some action which starts second activity, for example View::performClick()
    //...
    //Check Intent
    Intent intent = shadowActivity.peekNextStartedActivityForResult().intent;
    assertThat(intent.getStringExtra(MySecondActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE)).isEqualTo("blebleble");
    assertThat(intent.getComponent()).isEqualTo(new ComponentName(activity, MySecondActivity.class));
  }
}
```

This is similar to what I am doing. 
Please note that creating `Activity` by calling `new Activity()` will make Robolectric print warnings about creating activity improperly, this probably can be done better...

Comment: assertThat(intent.getComponent()).isEqualTo(new ComponentName(activity, MySecondActivity.class));
Not working for me Its saying cant pass Component Type in assertThat() method

Comment: @AbhijitChakra review your Assertions imports. This examples are using Fest,
try to use:
org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat(intent...)

Comment: Intent intent = shadowActivity.peekNextStartedActivityForResult().intent; gives back NULL

Comment: for shadowing: use Shadows.shadowOf(), it changed in Robolectric 3.0. For further reference about other changes, see this guide

Comment: The upgrade guide is https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: As of Robolectric 3.0 you need to use an extractor as in: ShadowActivity sa = (ShadowActivity) ShadowExtractor.extract(activity);

Comment: CAREFUL!!!, `.nextStartedService` returns the item at `index[0]` and removes it from the List. Therefore, if you call `.nextStartedService` a second time, it will return null in the case you only started one Service. The same happens with `.nextStartedActivity`. Written in Kotlin

Comment: In androidx, creating an activity should be easily done by using 
`val mainActivity = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)`
and then calling `mainActivity.onActivity{ activity: MainActivity -> //code }`

Answer (score 20):

Updating this for 3.1.2 as the answers above did not work for me:-

```
    loginButton.callOnClick();

    Intent startedIntent = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(startedIntent);
    assertEquals(NextActivity.class, shadowIntent.getIntentClass());
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of changes over time. This one worked tho, so kudos.

Comment: Any idea of how to do this from a fragment? In particular when you're testing a fragment via `startFragment` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294337/5111113

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by @MichK's answer, here is a complete running test using the `buildActivity` method chain from Robolectric 2.2+:

```
@Test
public void testStartScheduleActivity() {
    HomeScreenActivity homeActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(HomeScreenActivity.class).create().start().visible().get();
    ShadowActivity shadowHome = Robolectric.shadowOf(homeActivity);
    Button btnLaunchSchedule = (Button) homeActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnLaunchSchedule);
    Robolectric.clickOn(btnLaunchSchedule);

    assertThat(shadowHome.peekNextStartedActivityForResult().intent.getComponent(), equalTo(new ComponentName(homeActivity, ScheduleActivity.class)));
}
```

Comment: equalTo() not working what type of method can you please confirm me because its not working for me..May be i am doing some wrong approach is it a robolectric method

Answer (score 2):

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mMainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class)
            .create().start().visible().get();

    shadowActivity =Shadows.shadowOf(mMainActivity);
    hourlyButton = (Button) mMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.hourlyButton);
}
@Test
public void hourlyActivityButtonTest() throws Exception {

   Thread.sleep(5000);
    hourlyButton.performClick();
    Intent intent = shadowActivity.peekNextStartedActivityForResult().intent;
    assertThat(intent.getComponent()).isEqualTo(new ComponentName(mMainActivity, HourlyForecastActivity.class));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

James Neville's answer works on 4.3. However, I used the AndroidX API, Espresso and Kotlin:

```
// scenario initialization is done in @Before setUp method, I did it here for brevity
val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)

@Test fun test() {
    onView(withId(R.id.button_id)).perform(click())

    scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        val intent = shadowOf(activity).nextStartedActivity
        val shadowIntent = shadowOf(intent)

        assertEquals(SearchResultsActivity::class.java, shadowIntent.intentClass)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how does it looks like for the Robolectric 3

```
        // Click on the image view
    mShareLocationImageView.performClick();

    // Check the startActivityForResult for ShareUserLocationActivity has been triggered
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(mChatWindowsActivity);
    Intent intent = shadowActivity.peekNextStartedActivityForResult().intent;
    assertThat(intent).hasComponent(new ComponentName(mChatWindowsActivity, ShareUserLocationActivity.class));
```