# How can I test fragments with Robolectric?

Tags: android, robolectric

I know there is a `Robolectric.shadowOf(Fragment)` method and a `ShadowFragment` class, thought they aren't listed on the docs, but I can't make it work.

```
myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.from(activity), (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.container), null);
myFragment.onAttach(activity);
myFragment.onActivityCreated(null);
```

I'm working with API level 13 (Honeycomb).

Thanks.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**Edit #4 & #5**: In [Robolectric 3.*](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide), they split up the fragment starting functions.

For support fragments, you will need to add a [dependency](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.robolectric%3Ashadows-supportv4/view) to your `build.gradle`:

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-supportv4:3.8"
```

Import: [`org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment;`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/support/v4/SupportFragmentTestUtil.html)

For platform fragments, you don't need this dependency. Import: [`import static org.robolectric.util.FragmentTestUtil.startFragment;`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/util/FragmentTestUtil)

They both use the same name of `startFragment()`.

```
import static org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class YourFragmentTest
{
    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception
    {
        YourFragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance();
        startFragment( fragment );
        assertNotNull( fragment );
    }
}
```

**Edit #3**: Robolectric 2.4 has an [API for support and regular fragments](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/2.4/org/robolectric/util/FragmentTestUtil.html). You can either use the `newInstance()` pattern or use the constructor when constructing your `Fragment`'s.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.robolectric.util.FragmentTestUtil.startFragment;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class YourFragmentTest
{
    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception
    {
        YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
        startFragment( fragment );
        assertNotNull( fragment );
    }
}
```

**Edit #2**: There's a new helper if you're using support fragments ([one that supports regular activities/fragments should be in the next release](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/util/FragmentTestUtil.java)):

```
import static org.robolectric.util.FragmentTestUtil.startFragment;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    fragment = YourFragment.newInstance();
    startFragment( fragment );
}
```

**Edit**: If you upgraded to Robolectric 2.0:

```
public static void startFragment( Fragment fragment )
{
    FragmentActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity( FragmentActivity.class )
                                           .create()
                                           .start()
                                           .resume()
                                           .get();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add( fragment, null );
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**Original answer**

As the other commenter suggested, you do need to use the fragment manager (instead of calling the lifecycle methods you listed above).

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
public class YourFragmentTest
{
    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception
    {
        YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
        startFragment( yourFragment );
        assertNotNull( yourFragment );
    }
```

I create a test runner and have a function that starts up a fragment for me so I can use it everywhere.

```
public class MyTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner
{
    public MyTestRunner( Class<?> testClass ) throws InitializationError
    {
        super( testClass );
    }

    public static void startFragment( Fragment fragment )
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = new FragmentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add( fragment, null );
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you prove the above actually calls the fragment's lifecycle functions such as onCreateView?  After this my fragment is not null but members in my fragment that require onCreateView are still are.

Comment: I'd use the debugger to verify that lifecycle methods were called. Perhaps there is another issue with the fragment. Check out this example for testing view elements in fragments: https://github.com/colabug/Animation/blob/master/src/test/java/com/colabug/NewFragmentTest.java (main project: https://github.com/colabug/Animation/)

Comment: Thanks for the example, played around with your project and confirmed onCreateView is indeed being called so it must be something else wrong with my code as you say.

Comment: Given that startFragment(...) above is static and refers to no fields, it would seem to be more something you shove in a TestUtils class than a TestRunner..?

Comment: @android.weasel Not opposed to a separate utils class, but it seemed like overkill for this answer.

Comment: @android.weasel Also, typically you'd add more functions to the test runner. Check this out for more information: http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/08/android-unit-testing-with-robolectric.html

Comment: @colabug This example's MyTestRunner class is more the overkill - it has no functionality and degrades to a plain FragmentTestUtils class, leaving the test to RobolectricTestRunner. While a real-world MyTestRunner would bind in some new shadows, cluttering it with vaguely related statics risks semantic confusion: A test under one TestRunner might need to invoke a different TestRunner's static methods - not a problem if the statics are in TestUtility classes. It's not as if new classes are expensive, or that over-stuffing MyTestRunner saves anything in terms of (inexpensive) import statements.

Comment: @colabug By the way, useful article (aside from our difference about where to keep statics).

Comment: @android.weasel You're arguing a petty detail. It solved the question and works. Glad you enjoyed my article about testing.

Comment: This approach doesn't work with Robolectric 2.x :) Did you migrate already?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I haven't migrated. Do you have a solution you can share for the new way of doing things?

Comment: @colabug don't have it yet. We didn't migrate also :)

Comment: @EugenMartynov - Figured it out yesterday and updated the answer.

Comment: @colabug, nice! Thank you for sharing, but for me it still doesn't work: android.view.InflateException: XML file jar:/Users/eugen/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-res/4.1.2_r1_rc/android-res-4.1.2_r1_rc-real.jar!/res/layout/preference_list_fragment.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class <unknown> Time to contribute a little :)

Comment: @EugenMartynov I just finished debugging the same error message when I was passing a bundle to the Fragment. Make sure to try it with a vanilla/new/empty fragment to make sure it's not something weird with your fragment.

Comment: startFragment seems to be available for robolectric 2.x in org.robolectric.util.FragmentTestUtil

Comment: @Somatik - Thanks for the heads up, I edited my answer above to include this information. Note: It's only for the support version.

Comment: In case of using `fragmentTransaction.commit();` inside test you should also call `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();` becaouse  commit is executed asynchronously which cause a problem inside test environment.

Answer (score 37):

You guys are all doing this the hard way. Just use FragmentTestUtil.

```
FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(yourfragment);
```

Comment: This is a relatively new call, and it only works if you are using the support library fragments, FWIW.

Comment: Looks like they extended the class to both support and non-support Fragments (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/util/FragmentTestUtil.java)

Comment: If you want to test things that require the `Fragment` to be visible, you'll need to call `ActivityController.of(yourFragment.getActivity()).visible()`. This got me into trouble when trying to verify that my `Fragment`'s `onCreateOptionsMenu` was getting called correctly. Adding the call to `visible()` on the parent activity got it working.

Comment: Or you could directly user `FragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment()`

Comment: This has changed in 3.0. See my answer above with updated information.

Comment: Robolectric.buildFragment() is the up to date version

Comment: is there any way of getting a shadow of the fragment's activity in this case? The obvious `shadowOf(fragment.activity)` does not work

Answer (score 15):

Support fragments have been moved to module:

> shadows-support-v4

(as of July,2015, Robolectric v3.0)

Add a gradle dependency to app/build.gradle:

```
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
```

Then import to your Robolectric test java class:

```
import org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil;
```

Then you can start & use a support-v4 fragment for testing:

```
@Test
public void minimalFragmentTest() throws Exception {
    MyFunFragment fragment = new MyFunFragment();
    SupportFragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment(fragment);
    assertThat(fragment.getView()).isNotNull();
}
```

References:

- [github changelog](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commit/b7eb377f5caa86ab2cd106d3bd52a87755b766c5), moving support fragments to different module

Comment: Thanks, figured this out the hard way this morning and then updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Old android fragments are already deprecated, seems like support fragments soon will be deprecated too. To test androidx fragments you can use fragment scenarios with robolectric https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing

```
testImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.2'
```

```
val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<MyFragment>()
scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
    assertNotNull(fragment.view.synteticInflatedView)
}
```

Comment: How could we use Robolectric with Fragment scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to create a `FragmentTransaction` using the `FragmentManager`, then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add that in Robolectric 2.0 even after doing:

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
fragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
fragment.getDialog();  //This stills returns null
```

It still returned null for me. what I did was to add `activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransaction();` and it worked.

It seems robolectric doesn't run this for some reason. it seems that maybe the Looper is paused or something. any way this worked for me and it looks like this:

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
fragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
fragment.getDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment, AppCompatActivity::class.java)
```

If the activity is extending `AppCompatActivity`

This is using Kotlin