# Robolectric fails to inflate Views in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-inflate, robolectric, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to test the following method of a `DialogFragment`:

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_fileproperties_layout, null);
        thumbImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesThumb);
        nameTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesName);
        typeTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesTypeValue);
        locationTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesLocationValue);
        sizeTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesSizeValue);
        numberOfFilesLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesNumOfFilesLayout);
        numberOfFilesTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesNumOfFilesValue);
        lastModifiedLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesLastModifiedLayout);
        lastModifiedTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesLastModifiedValue);
        hiddenCheckbox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesHiddenCheckbox);
        hiddenCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        typeCategoryTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesCategoryType);
        infoCategoryTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesCategoryInfo);
        attributesCategoryTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.filePropertiesCategoryAttributes);
        populateViews();
        if (selectedFiles.size() == 1) {
            if (selectedFiles.get(0).isFile()) {
                populateViewsFile();
            } else {
                populateViewsFolder();
            }
        } else {
            populateViewsMultiple();
        }
        toggleHiddenOnExit = false;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(rootView).setTitle(R.string.properties)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, this)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, this);
        return builder.create();
    }
```

The `populateViews()` method looks like the following:

```
private void populateViews() {
        final int backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray);
        final int textColor = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black);
        typeCategoryTextView.setText(R.string.type);
        typeCategoryTextView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        typeCategoryTextView.setTextColor(textColor);
        infoCategoryTextView.setText(R.string.info);
        infoCategoryTextView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        infoCategoryTextView.setTextColor(textColor);
        attributesCategoryTextView.setText(R.string.attributes);
        attributesCategoryTextView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        attributesCategoryTextView.setTextColor(textColor);
    }
```

Now, in the test method looks like this:

```
@Test
    public void testCreateDialogForAFile() {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/file.txt");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogUtils.e(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
        files.add(file);
        dialog.setSelectedFiles(files);
        assertNotNull("onCreateDialog not null", dialog.onCreateDialog(null));
        file.delete();
    }
```

And here's the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.foo.bar.fragment.dialog.FooDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(FooDialogFragment.java:93)
    at com.foo.bar.fragment.dialog.FooDialogFragmentTest.testCreateDialogForAFile(FooDialogFragmentTest.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

The `Views` aren't inflated and the test fails. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the [ShadowDialogFragment](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowDialogFragment.java) is not implemented properly in Robolectric. There is `show()` method implemented and no `onCreateDialog()`. One solution could be implementing it yourself and push to the repository.

### edit:

I've read your comment, and I've taken a closer look at sources. The dialog is created and attached in `show()` method of shadow implementation.

Try to invoke show() before testing the views:

```
dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "tag");
assertNotNull("dialog not null", dialogFragment.getDialog());
```

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903280/538169) will help you with `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Actually onCreateDialog() runs well for other DialogFragment implementations of mine. Problem is in View inflating, and I need to test that the Views are inflated correctly and that proper data is bound.

Comment: Seems still the case in 2015.