# Override Dagger Module in Robolectric Tests

Tags: android, robolectric, dagger

I'm working on an `Android` application and I've been using `Dagger` for dependency injection.

I'm trying to now test a fragment which has one of these dependencies, let's call it `ProductsService`.

In my `Robolectric` test I have got as far as having a test module that overrides `ProductsService`:

```
    @Module(
        includes = ProductsModule.class,
        injects = {
                Fragment.class,
                FragmentTest.class
        },
        overrides = true
)
static class MockProductsModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ProductsService providesProductsService() {
        return Mockito.mock(ProductsService.class);
    }
}
```

In my test, in order to run my fragment I construct it as follows (as seen here [How can I test fragments with Robolectric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333354/how-can-i-test-fragments-with-robolectric))

```
        FragmentActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class)
            .create()
            .start()
            .resume()
            .get();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The problem is, during this creation it makes call to `Dagger` to satisfy it's dependencies:

```
((MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).inject(this);
```

How do I override the object graph created when the fragment is created, to use the `MockProductsModule` I declare in my test?

Answer (score 12):

I suppose you are creating the object graph in `Application.onCreate()`. If that's the case and if you're using Robolectric 2, you can create a test application as explained [here](http://robolectric.blogspot.de/2013/04/the-test-lifecycle-in-20.html) and create an object graph for your tests with your test modules (prod and test application must inherit from the same base class). For more info on this, you can have a look [here](https://plus.google.com/103905139322505326276/posts/4TXHu8G38Gj). Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I made a method to inject graph object and used that in tests but your solution doesn't have drawbacks of smell design (but have drawbacks of smell tests :)). Thank you!