# Robolectric, How to assert activity is created and there is no exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, junit5

I want to assert that activity is successfully **created** with given condition.
However, there is nothing like

> controller.get().isCreated

My code is:

```
@get:Rule
val exception: ExpectedException = ExpectedException.none()

@Test
fun test_example() {
    // Given
    val intent = getMyIntent()

    // When
    val controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(
            MyActivity::class.java,
            intent
    ).setup()

    // Then
    // no exception is expected and
    assertTrue(controller != null)
}
```

Yes, if there is any exception, this test would fail. 
However, I want to explicitly assert that my activity is successfully created.

Comment: Have you searched on StackOverflow before posting your question? There is a very high chance that your question has been previously answered and your question might be closed for being a duplicate. Here are two that I looked up one using robolectric the other using espresso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896088/testing-that-button-starts-an-activity-with-robolectric and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998659/espresso-how-can-i-check-if-an-activity-is-launched-after-performing-a-certain

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf I cannot find answers from both of it. I want to use robolectric and the answer is too old and the solution is deprecated

Comment: You're referring to the accepted answers being from older version of robolectric. Scroll down and you'll see another answer for version 3 upwards. Linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39674693/2119723

Comment: Thank you for the information. But nextStartedActivity() returns null, because I didn't click any button. What I want is getCurrentActivity()